# align text and toggle button in html css

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have created a custom toggle button with html input checkbox and with custom css which looks like this
[image]

As you can see the texts and toggle buttons are not aligned, I tried adding margin/padding/heights nothing worked.
Here is the html and corresponding css ->

```
<h5 style="display:inline" class="switch">Company</h5>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="company-survey-checker">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
<h5 style="display:inline">Survey</h5>
```

And the css operating here is ->

```
<style>
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
```

Ideally the texts and toggle buttons should be on the same line but i am finding it difficult to achieve it , any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:middle` to your `label`

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h5 style="display:inline" class="switch">Company</h5>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="company-survey-checker">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
<h5 style="display:inline">Survey</h5>
```